# Wine Regedit: не сохраняются изменения

Tags: ubuntu

Делаю изменения в реестре, но они не сохраняются, почему?

Answer (score 1):

может быть по тому, что нет прав на запись. Проверьте права на system.reg user.reg userdef.reg

Comment: где это все находится и что я там должен найти?

Comment: /home/имя-пользователя/.wine